# Jquery, Stopped queued functions and reset to original function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, function

So I am trying to get this function to work. I have made other functions like this before I just like to make new things just for fun. As of now I am trying to make this image that flashes out and back in as a new image. so far it works fine but the only problem is that it gets overloaded and acts funny when clicked repeatedly. I tried putting it in JSfiddle but some of the animations appeared to not make it through. regardless I was wondering if there was a way to, if you click on something and start the function again while the original time it was clicked has not finished processing through. I could stop the function and reset it back to the beginning instead of watching the image flicker again and again until it works through the amount of times it was clicked.

HTML

```
<div id="menuImageDiv">
<div id="menuImageLeft"><</div>
<img id="menuImage" src="pictures/gingerbread.JPG">
<div id="menuImageRight">></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $(function(){
      var i = 0;
    var cars = ['pictures/gingerbread.JPG', 'pictures/cupcake.JPG','pictures/cake.JPG'];
    var delay = 500
    function startSlide(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      var menuimage=$("#menuImage")
      i ++;
      i = i % cars.length;
        menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay).promise().done(function(){
          menuimage.attr('src', cars[i]).promise().done(function(){
              menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay)
          });
        });

      }, delay*10)
    }
    function stopSlide(){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
    $("document").ready(function(){
    var menuimage=$("#menuImage");
    var right = $("#menuImageRight");
      right.click(function(){
        menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay).promise().done(function(){
          menuimage.attr('src', cars[i]).promise().done(function(){
              menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay)
          });
        });
        i ++;
        i = i % cars.length;
    console.log(i);
      })
    })
    $("document").ready(function(){

      var menuimage=$("#menuImage")
      var left = $("#menuImageLeft")
        left.click(function(){
          menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay).promise().done(function(){
            menuimage.attr('src', cars[i]).promise().done(function(){
                menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay)
            });
          });
          i --;
          i = i % cars.length;
          if (i<=-1){
            i=cars.length-1;
          }
        })
    })

    startSlide();
    $("#menuImageDiv").mouseenter(stopSlide).mouseleave(startSlide)
    })
```

CSS

```
     #menuImageDiv{
                z-index:0;
                position:relative;
                height:500px;
                width:100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                top:-30px;
            }
            #menuImage{
                width:100%;
                min-height:500px;
                max-height:550px;
            }
            #menuImageLeft{
                cursor:  url(http://i68.tinypic.com/2zq4h2g.jpg), auto;
                margin:auto 0;
                font-size:50px;
                background:#3a3a3a;
                padding:0 25px;
                opacity:0;
                top:50px;
                position:absolute;
                float:left;
                z-index:5;
                width:47%;
                height:400px;
            }
            #menuImageRight{
                cursor:  url(http://i63.tinypic.com/2mni1ky.jpg), auto;
                font-size:50px;
                background:#3a3a3a;
                padding:0 25px;
                opacity:0;
                top:50px;
                float:right;
                position:absolute;
                z-index:5;
                width:50%;
                height:400px;
                left:50%
            }
            .nopacity{
              opacity:0;
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nathanahartmann/30d0ause/8/

P.S. I've been looking into .stopPropogation() and .stopImmediatePropogation() and .stop() and none of them have worked as desired.

Comment: why do you use promises ?

Comment: first of all, $(document).ready(function() {}) and $(function() {}) is the same and you use it nested. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/ . Why do you do three times the same menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity'... the code would be more readable if you source this part out in a function.

Comment: http://i65.tinypic.com/2s64ho4.jpg

It was giving me this error. .promise() helped overcome this error.

Comment: and the `done` why did you use it? :))

Comment: are you asking me or trying to see if I know why I use it?

Comment: i am asking,this part of your code seems weird to me, toggleClass is not an asynchronous function

Comment: why do you even toggle a class in the first place?

Comment: oh, well I was originally using it so it would wait until done toggleClass is done, then change the image. I added this because before, when I had them seperated, it would toggle class, and then while the animation was processing, it would change the image. with done, it waits until the first toggleClass is finished, then changes the image, and then toggleClass happens again.

Comment: this is simpler https://jsfiddle.net/30d0ause/9/

Comment: I use it to change opacity, I'm not sure, I'm still kind of new and trying to figure these things out. I know I can directly change the CSS attribute, this is just the current way I did it at the time.

Comment: oh, the class toggle was to have it fade in and fade out, since its and animation to change opacity from 0, then it changes the source of the image, and then changes opacity back to 1.

Comment: The animations didn't make it into jsFiddle for some reason. but they are functioning on my web browser when I run the code.

Comment: "The animations didn't make it into jsFiddle", you forget the jquery ui library that is why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery. Please look at these documentation.

[jQuery Finish](https://api.jquery.com/finish/)

[jQuery Stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: somehow did not see .finish().... I've been staring at the entire list of jquery functions for the past 30 minutes, didn't see that -.-. ended up getting it to work pretty much as desired. I appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI [toggleClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) has a callback function for when the animation completes

```
menuimage.finish().toggleClass('nopacity', delay,function(){
 menuimage.attr('src', cars[i]);
 menuimage.toggleClass('nopacity', delay);
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/w4dnb7qd/

Comment: I already tried this. Somehow it got the toggleClass to work, but the attr never changed when I switched to an array. I'm not sure why.

Comment: but it still has the same problem I was talking about. That is that if you click it multiple times, it continues to go through the process the amount of times it was clicked. I wanted a way to kill all queued actions and just return the method once.

Comment: yep, that's what I did with my code once I found out about finish :] works like a charm